# How to get Python to log on to a website, load a presaved data search and then export the data page by page

Tags: python, excel, splinter

I am trying to write a python script that will load a presaved search for data on a webpage(this is the Orbis dataset accessed through a library), and then export the data to excel or CSV. This involves:
Starting here:

1. [link](https://orbis-bvdinfo-com.proxy.lib.umich.edu/version-2014224/Search.QuickSearch.serv?_cid=0&context=1EQY9R18YCPGB2C)
   I need to click on the 'view list of results' tab (**this I can do**)
2. The results show up 25 companies at a time, which can be exported to excel by clicking on an `export to excel' button, and then I need a loop that will change the entry for which page of the results it is (from 1  to 40,000), and export each page one at a time. **(This I can partially do)**

**Edit 2:**
To narrow the question, I have can automate logging on, setting up my search and getting to the export page. I am using splinter. However, the export window is a popup, and splinter cannot (to the best of my knowledge) navigate to the popup, fill in the conditions for export and click on the export.

**Question**  Is there a way (with splinter or otherwise) to navigate to the popup window so I am communicating with it? Here is my code:

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit('https://weblogin.umich.edu/?cosign-www.lib&https://www.lib.umich.edu/cgi/l/login/proxy-session-init-qurl?qurl=https%3a%2f%2forbis2.bvdep.com%2fip')
browser.fill('login', 'username')
browser.fill('password', 'psswd')
browser.find_by_value('Log In').click()
browser.find_by_id('ContentContainer1_ctl00_Content_QuickSearch1_ctl02_TabSavedSearchesTd').click()

# Problem, here firefox doesn't save the searches
test_link= browser.find_link_by_text("My Search 1")
test_link.click()

#test entry into text field

# browser.fill('ContentContainer1$ctl00$Header$ctl00$ctl07$SearchText2008','xyz')

test_link= browser.find_link_by_text("Export")
test_link.click()

# Problem -- here the export comes out as a popup, then the scraper can't follow it
# browser.visit('newlink-popup')
# browser.fill('RANGEFROM', '1')  # Therefore can't use this command`
```

Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: yes, there is a way... but http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also, it's a pain in the rear.